# Facebook login on localhost - connection not secure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, http, https

I am adding a Facebook login to our React project, using Facebook Javascript SDK.
I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

When I click the login button which I added to the page, following error is shown:

**Facebook has detected X isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.
Until X updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log into it.**

[image]

My app is in development mode, which should mean (according Facebook docs) that localhost redirects are allowed, but it isn't so.

I have also tried adding localhost to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in Facebook developers page, but it didn't solve the problem.

I have managed to solve the problem partially by using ngrok following this [tutorial](https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/04/16/using-ngrok-with-facebook-oauth-login/), but it is very buggy (sometimes doesn't work) and impractical to work with, as I often have to restart whole server and everything.

Comment: did you try devcert instead of ngrok?

Comment: I tried to implement it unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 14):

You should use the 'Create Test App' which will create an test app for an existing live account. The just use the test app's ID on your development.

[image]

Comment: Seems my old test app didn't work, creating a new test app under a live app now works. Not sure if it was a question of creating a new test app, or the way I created it, but this works - thanks!

Comment: as of dec 25th, 2021, this still works (creating new test app under a live app) - maybe should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

**In case of angular**: try to serve your app in secured socket layer true mode facebook is detecting insecure connection

Use the following command: **ng serve --ssl true**

Answer (score 3):

First you need to use a domain name, you can do this in your hosts file

/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   test.example.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

and then you need to update your start script like

package.json:

```
...
"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
...
```

and start your reactjs app with :

```
npm run start
```

then you will see your app is running on `https://test.example.com` and of course you have to add this domain to your facebook app as trusted url

Answer (score 2):

**In React** Just do `HTTPS=true npm start` and it will take care of https on the localhost. The boolean `HTTPS=true` will be used to tell npm that it needs to start the `https` connection.

Answer (score 2):

As of today you can't use just http://localhost. I'll suggest to consider services like https://ngrok.com/.

Comment: Source of your statement ?

Comment: Experience. I spent half a day trying to use localhost and it doesn't worth battling the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Due security changes on facebook you can only log in from simple HTTP if you disable the https and are in development model on your facebook app, here is an explanatory image

[image: Correct fb configuration to enable login from http instead of https]

Comment: If we could turn off **Enforce HTTPS** we would just do so! The problem is we can't. Not anymore at least. So therein lies the problem.

Comment: I think we should be talking about different stuff, because this is the dev flow I usually follow (set my app as development, work locally, the publish again, I just did it this morning), one thing, just disabling enforce does not do the trick, you need to switch to dev mode on facebook, and why you say you CANT disable it?

Comment: Because It's forced to "on" and cannot be changed. It is explicitly stated in the doc: 'On October 6, 2018, all apps will be required to use HTTPS.' (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea)

Comment: yes, when it's in production, that's why you need to switch to dev mode to be able to run from nonsecure site like localhost, can you show how is your face app configured?

Comment: Even in dev mode it's forced to "on" and cannot be changed. But btw, the problem for me was a weird Ruby gem-specific problem: I was supposed to set the complete callback URL instead of just the path portion like (`/callback`).

Comment: This is still an issue - even in Development mode, **Enforce HTTPS** cannot be disabled 

Answer (score 0):

I confirm you can use callback `http://localhost` without SSL when your app is in status "In Development".

I came here because my callback was `http://localhost.localdomain`, a hack I made in pre-2018 for Facebook auth actually, and it was not working on Chome 78.

Comment: Problem is most people cannot turn off 'In Development'

Comment: Well, this "In Development' mode was not designed upfront to be switched back, the same way once your app is in prod, you cannot take it off for test. I've always used two Facebook apps ID, with one purposefully for dev. And my database works well with both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was using the url `http://127.0.0.1` but facebook requires you to use `http://localhost` instead and this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that was quick and worked for me is to download the ngrok from here: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup,

Unzip it inside the project.
I have a laravel project, so before opening the ngrok, try running php artisan serve command. now open ngrok and type the command ngrok http [http:127.0.01:8000]
you will get the output:

```
Forwarding   http://1cb0-163-47-148-175.ngrok.io ->  http://127.0.0.1:8000                              Forwarding                    
             https://1cb0-163-47-148-175.ngrok.io -> http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

now change the redirect url of facebook login with https in
Valid OAuth Redirect URIs and your service class.

```
'redirect' => 'https://1cb0-163-47-148-175.ngrok.io/auth/facebook/callback
```

ps: I have used test app version in a development mode

Answer (score -1):

No need to use ngrok or the likes.

Make sure you've specified your *development mode* Facebook application's `app-id` in

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{app-id}',
        cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
        xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
        version    : '{api-version}'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });
...
```

And restart the server after this update.